# Best way to store dates in MySQL database for data visualize

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, date, datetime

I make some website which will be similar to basic TODO List applications. For a single row I always store single date and I basicly dont need hours and seconds, date is just fine.

**How I use data:**
I have PHP backend which make SQL select and then create JSON from this data and give it frontend which is created in AngularJS.

**What I want to do with data:** 
I want to compare data and visualize it with graphs. I am not sure whats the best way to store this kind of values.

**Things I consider:**

1. Unix TIME - I feel like its really easy to work with numbers in any language and also easy to compare and visualize
2. MySQL Date - I'm not sure because I think that inside MySQL date format should be really usefull but I'm not sure how to compare date in format like: YYYY-MM-DD
3. MySQL Datetime - Basicly same as before just with added time, I dont think this can be usefull for me.

I will be really happy your opinion and advise which can help me. Also advantage of each method because I mentioned just advantage of UNIX TIME because number are easy to compare. It's also easy I miss something relevant how to store date in database so if there is other option please don't hesitate to speak about it.

Thanks

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Based on opinion I would opt for MySQL Date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would opt for MySQL Date.

Lets say we have a table called `my_table` which has a `Date` column named `my_date`.

You can actually interact with it in much the same way as you can a `timestamp`. Assuming `my_date` is the date that the item was created...

```
// Where it was created after 1st Jan
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_date > '2016-01-01'

// Where it was created in Jan
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND 2015-01-31

// Where it was created in the last 7 days
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), my_date) <= 7
```